# Как отключить предупреждения в vsc c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, settings

Компилятор постоянно предупреждает о возможных ошибках, подчеркивая код C# бесячим желтым цветом и, тыча своими грязными пальцами, кричит что "Ты создал переменную, но не использовал ее!", и т.д. Как их отключить?

Comment: Может лучше привести код в порядок?

Comment: Да он эти предупреждения потом убирает, например когда я все таки использую переменные в коде. Меня просто бесит само наличие этих предупреждений.

Comment: Так для этого сделано, что бы бесило и вы устраняли ) Если вам уж очень хочется не видеть собственных ошибок и недочетов, то скорее всего [это ответ на вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552414/how-to-disable-c-error-checking-in-vs-code)

Comment: Включить опцию [TreatWarningsAsErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#treatwarningsaserrors) - теперь вместо жёлтого цвета будет красный.

Comment: Ахах, не, еще хуже) как их вообще отключить?

Comment: Я вам выше ссылку оставил, там пишут: Open up the command palette (CTRL + SHIFT + P) - > C/Cpp: Toggle Error Squiggles. This will disable all error warnings and highlighting - может поможет. И там дополнение есть: Update: April 2020: it is now called "c/c++: Disable Error Squiggles"

Comment: Используйте блокнот, раз вам не нужна помощь IDE. Подсказки, особенно такие очевидные - это одна из самых важных вещей в любой IDE, которая позволяет вам, программисту не совершить критичную ошибку в коде. Ну, если вы всеж хотите игнорировать предложенную вам помощь, то создайте [editorconfig файл](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options) и пропишите в нем нужные уровни оповещения под нужные правила.

Comment: Ну, знаете, такая очевидное предупреждение как "вы не использовали переменную" мне не нужно. Ну, что ж, способ тот устарел. Придется терпеть.

Comment: Ну раз вы гадите в коде, а другие этого не хотят видеть, да, такое очевидное предупреждение нужно, и яб сказал, обязательно. И какой это способ устарел? Я вам дал ссылку на официальную документацию по настройке стиля кода, где даже про расширение для VS Code говорят, которое поможет вам настроить все. Лучше конечно поперек прочитать текст и терпеть, да...